# CSS: How to make a table cell auto shrink or expand to make a table keep its size?

Tags: html, css

So I have a 3-column table that I want to show like

Example Layout 1:

```
A BBBBBBBBBB C
A B          C
A BBBBBBB... C
```

Example Layout 2:

```
A B... CCCCCCC
A B    C
```

Example Layout 3:

```
A  B        C    
AA BB       CC
```

(Below is optional case that I can ignore but better if )

Example Layout 4:

```
AA B... CCCC..
A  BB   CC
```

Example Layout 5:

```
A... B... C...
AA   BB   CC
```

So the rule is like

1. Table width is determined by parent div. It cannot be changed.
2. Row height is always constant.
3. A and C columns are kept their minimized sizes to display full content.
4. B will shrink to B... if the remaining space is compact.
5. B will expand to full width if A and C takes just a little space.
6. Optional: if B is at its minimum size and A and/or C still cannot fit, try apply the same rule of 1~5 to to other columns one by one till we finish

What I tried was like, but this won't make table stay as its size.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: block;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.autoCol {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:150px">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="autoCol">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaaa</td>
      <td class="autoCol">bbbbbb</td>
      <td>cccc</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Table cells always show their full content. You need to use a wrapper element inside the cell which you can limit.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint of how to do that?

Comment: As I said, use a wrapper element inside the cell, and apply your limiting CSS to that.

Comment: I believe I can limit the cell size to a constant value, but how can I know A and C's minimized full content size over all rows, and, apply the rest space to cells of B column?

Comment: @K--, Do you need this result? - https://i.ibb.co/9sTGXBh/2021-04-09-15-04-51.png. The total width of the table is 150px.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yes I believe that's what I wanted. And I just find out that I need only a "." before autoCol.

Comment: @K--, Will there always be only 3 fields? Or maybe there will be more fields? Also, you have a typo here - `</tablet>`. And 150px, is this the maximum width of the table?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thanks. The post was edited. There could be many columns but to keep it simple I assume the maximum width will no less than the width needed to render "x..." multiples column number. Anyway for 3 columns 150px is the fixed width of the table, not the maximum width. If columns are short enough, expand B column to keep A and C fully shown in their minimized size. Like in Layout 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        max-width: 150px;
    }
    
    table td {
        width:100%;
    }
    
    table td.shrink {
        white-space:nowrap
    }
```